# Don't understand Linux command 'sort'

Tags: linux, shell, sorting

Could someone please tell me what will be displayed if the Linux command:

```
sort -k3,3nr -k2,2 exam1.data | head -1
```

is entered for `exam1.data` below?

I am pretty sure the correct answer is the line with the name "Allen,_Jenna" in it, but I am not sure why and need an explanation as to what each line in the command line is supposed to be doing.

```
arctic> cat exam1.data
01 Ozment,_Tony      19  21  13  15
04 McCutcheon,_Tom   33  25  79  29
10 Cook,_Sam         30  92  24  30
11 Dambo,_Nancy       9   3   0   5
12 Hollie,_Nicole    31  44   2  14
15 Gaines,_Valerie   33  76  14  18
25 Clouden,_Kate     33 133  21 125
33 Allen,_Jenna      33 105  32  52
42 Bell,_Kathleen    19  20   0  15
```

Comment: Q: Are you familiar with the Linux command "man", as in [man sort](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html)?  "Man" will tell you what each option in the command means, and often give helpful examples.  See also: https://www.tecmint.com/sort-command-linux/. `-k3,3nr` means "Sort on column 3 through column 3, treat it as a number (not text), and sort in reverse order".  `-k2,2` does a sub-sort, by col#2.

Comment: Read [sort(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) and try `sort --help` in a terminal

Comment: Questions about the Linux operating system and its utilities are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed correct. The primary key definition `3,3nr` means field 3, numeric, reverse order. That will put all the `33` entries on top.

The secondary key definition `2,2` will, within the primary groups, sort on field 2 in ascending order and the first `33` row in that case will be the one starting with `A`.

This may become clearer if you simply execute the command *without* piping through `head`. Then you'll see the primary/secondary sorting (I've added blank lines to delineate the primary groups):

```
33 Allen,_Jenna      33 105  32  52
25 Clouden,_Kate     33 133  21 125
15 Gaines,_Valerie   33  76  14  18
04 McCutcheon,_Tom   33  25  79  29

12 Hollie,_Nicole    31  44   2  14

10 Cook,_Sam         30  92  24  30

42 Bell,_Kathleen    19  20   0  15
01 Ozment,_Tony      19  21  13  15

11 Dambo,_Nancy       9   3   0   5
```

If you're interested in how the key definitions works regarding field selection, you can examine the `man` page for `sort`, but I've copied the relevant bit below:

> `KEYDEF` is `F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]]` for start and stop position, where `F` is a field number and `C` a character position in the field; both are origin 1, and the stop position defaults to the line's end. *[Then some details about options, which you can go to the `man` page to investigate further, I've explained the two that you're using - pax].*

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I have one more question. When '-k' is used, and in this case when '-k' was used 2,2 was placed after it. Does the 2,2 mean that the contents should be sorted based on the items in column 2(the names) in exam1.data? Now i am not sure I understand that part. I have read explanations online about the -k command and read about it in the man pages and still do not understand.

Comment: @CarolineB: yes, `-k2,2` means use the whole of column 2 as this sort key segment. Without the second number, it uses from the start of column 2 to the end of the line.

Comment: @CarolineB: you'll notice that I said above that `-k3,3` means "column 3, through column 3".  In contrast, `-k3` (without the ",3") would mean "column 3 through end-of-line".  You'll also notice that in `KEYDEF is F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]]`, the "[]" square brackets mean *OPTIONAL* parameters.  In other words, the second [,F...] is optional.  Allowing for either "-k3", or "-k3,3".  Hopefully that "helps" (rather than "confuses")...

Comment: @paxdiablo Hi, man, how can I contact you? would you leave your e-mail?

Comment: @CarolineB Do not ask new questions in the comments. Open another question instead. [ask]